# Is there any good documentation for Nuget.targets file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am currently trying to understand Packet Management using Nuget and the old code base I am asked to compile uses Nuget for Package Management.

Whenever I compile the project, I am getting the below error :

```
RestorePackages:
  "...\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\main\Kron.Shared.Model\packages.config" -source   -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\main\ "

C:\main\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

C:\main\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\main\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\main\Krono.Shared.Model\packages.config" -source   -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\main\ "" exited with code 1.
```

So I tried opening the Nuget.targets file and tried to understand what is going on inside. Its been days I could not figure out anything useful. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/yQo/nuget-aspnet-5-visual-studio-2015-dnx-package-manager-in-vs2015-rc-fails-on-installing-restoring-some-packages) article. If it does not resolve your problem add more context information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no comprehensive documentation for Nuget.targets (I have been searching over the internet for more than 2 days)

For the issue I was facing, the below post helped me solve :
http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2012/08/disable-nuget-package-restore.html

Bottomline :
1. Enabling Nuget Packet Restore is easy
2. Disabling Packet Restore is not easy as it involves visiting all the project files and removing the few entries outlined in the above blog